# $(document).ready does not work

Tags: ajax

When I click the submit button, why `<div>` does not show 'Loading...'? 
I have very less knowledge about jQuery and Ajax. Please help me with simple explanations. Thanks

```
    <head>
  <script type="text/javascript" 
     src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(document).ready( function(e) {

            $(".frmUpload").on('submit',(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    $(".upload-msg").text('Loading...');

            });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<h1>Ajax Image Upload</h1>
        <form action="" method="post" class="frmUpload">
            <input type="file" name="photoUpload" id="ajaxUpload">
            <input type="submit" value="UPLOAD">
        </form>
        <div class="img-preview"></div>
        <div class="upload-msg"></div>
```

Comment: `$(".upload-msg")` is a class selector. there's no guarantee that that DOM query will return a single node. If you want to select a particular node, use an ID (that's what they're for: to IDentify a specific node). Classes are for groups/categories of elements, and are best used for styling (CSS)

Comment: Look at your console.

Comment: Console is a browse output window which enlists all your request , response to and from the server. It will also have errors mentioned if you have kind of client side errors such as missing parenthesis in this case, undefined variables, sometimes images not found. All this will be mentioned in your console. It makes debugging easier on the client side. If can be access in all browsers by hitting F12

Comment: The below link tell you how to access console Windows in different browser. http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've missed an ending `)`.

```
$(document).ready( function(e) {

        $(".frmUpload").on('submit',(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(".upload-msg").text('Loading...');

        }));
});
```

Works better, notice the `}))`. You don't strictly need the `(` before the function in `'submit', (function` , so you can alternatively remove that one.